# C++ Parser/Model for Java

Tags: java, c++, model, parsing

I was wondering if anyone knows of existing C++ parsers/code models that can be used programmatically in Java. I'm looking for something similar to the Eclipse CDT that can be used as a library from Java (and that does not rely upon Eclipse). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to build your own C++ parser. It'll kill you.

You already know about the Eclipse CDT project:
www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecl-cdt3/index.html 
AFAIK, that parser is, well, a bit fuzzy around the edges. YMMV.
Advantage: in Java (and in Eclipse if you care).
If you want to process C++, and do it in Java, this might
be your only practical choice.

There is also our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit C++ front end:
http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html
Works with a wide variety of C++ dialects (ANSI, GNU, MSVC 2005/2008),
tested by fire on millions of lines of code.
Disadvantage from your point of view: Not in Java.
But if you *really* want to analyze C++, making a rule
that you are only willing to do it in Java might not
serve you the best.

Answer (score 0):

There are some incomplete LALR grammars for parser generators like Lex, Yacc, Antlr, Jack, etc.

C++ has an undecidable syntax grammar, so LALR and BNR grammars will always be incomplete, but as long as you're not trying to write a C++ compiler, they should be good enough.

Comment: C++ is not undecidable.  It is not LR or LALR, which means it is hard to parse using those parser technologies.  That's only a small pain compared to doing symbol table construction for C++, which is a royal bitch (600 pages of C++ standard ...).   Frankly, it is just silly to try to roll your own C++ parser unless that's how you want to make your living.

Comment: My mistake. It being "undecidable" is a comment I frequently see, rarely disputed. I guess I misunderstood the meaning of "undecidable."

Comment: C++ is really undecidable because parse trees sometimes depend on semantic variables. "Undecidability" here means that the Halting problem can be reduced to the parsing of C++.
See http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/web-vs-c++.html#misfeature-3

Comment: @dmitry: So how is that real C++ compilers can parse C++ source code? You might argue they're all broken; but if there really is an undecidable choice in parsing then the language won't be useful there and presumably the language committee will change the meaning of language there to make real compilers manageable. However, I'm not convinced on undecidability; your paper says there are no C++ compilers that separate parsing from semantic analysis. Our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit does just that by retaining ambiguous parses are resolving them later when it has sufficient information.

Answer (score -1):

There are some C++ grammars out there for JavaCC.  Try google.

Comment: I don't think you'll get a robust JavaCC grammar for C++. If you do, you still have to worry about preprocessor handling.
Both of the are small pain compared to doing symbol table construction for C++, which is a royal bitch (600 pages of C++ standard ...).

Comment: You can either skip pre-processing or run it independently as a first pass via something like "g++ -E".  ---  Books like the ARM (Annotated C++ Reference Manual), (a little outdated -- C++ has been improved since then), include the C++ grammar.  I thought the goal here was parsing, not compiling.  Symbol table is therefore unnecessary.  I have written C++ JavaCC parsers in ages past.  Open source solutions do exist.

Comment: The OP wasn't clear what he wanted to do.  In any case, there's not a lot you can do to C++ without a symbol table, so unless he's looking for very limited information, he needs one.