# Extract function names from c/c++ source code in java

Tags: java, c++, c, ctags

I need to extract from c/c++ source code files, function/class/macro names and their locations in their files. I need to do this in java and over a lot of files (~100/150). How can I do this?

So basically I need something similar to ctags but in java.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest thing to do would probably be to write a [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) wrapper for ctags!

You could also look at [finding a C++ parser in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675255/c-parser-model-for-java). Maybe [abduct the parser Eclipse uses for syntax highlighting](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecl-cdt3/index.html). Writing your own parser will be extremely painful since it's not a LALR grammar (I know this from experience).

Comment: I don't like to have ctags as dependence of my application :(

I will probably look for a C++ parser in java as you suggest. Thanks :)

Comment: Alternatively, you can use other tools and parse the result, for example g++ or clang++ to process and generate a parseable file.